# Can't hide home indicator and defer bottom system gesture at the same time

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use the `UIViewController` properties `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` and `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures`. I'm using them like this:

```
override var prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
override var preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures: UIRectEdge {
    [.bottom, .left, .right, .top]
}
```

but the problem is that when I do this, it doesn't defer the bottom screen edge system gesture. If I remove `prefersHomeIndicatorAutoHidden` then it does defer it. However, in this case the home indicator only fades and doesn't disappear. How can I use both?